# anyone heard of MCUDEV_TFT1.44 display? I can't figure out how to connect it to Arduino

Tags: display, tft

I bought this tft display on Aliexpress:
https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005001579367288.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.72164c4doyqAub

it says "MCUDEV_TFT1.44" below the display.

[image]

I can't find online how to connect it to Arduino.
The pins are as follows:
BLK RS RST CS SC DI GND VCC

on Aliexpress it says "Drive IC: ST7735" but I googled ST7735 displays and they have different pins.
Anyone has any idea?
Thanks!

Comment: BLK is probably Back Light (K)Cathode. RS is Register Select. RST is RESET. CS is Chip Select. SC is SCK. DI is MOSI.

Comment: @Majenko THANK YOU! I made it work :)

Comment: can you share you setting anh scheme connect

Comment: @DầuĐậuPhụ I posted it as an answer if you are still interested

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else have the same display and wondering how to make it work, here is how I connected and the script I used.

I couldn't find my display model so I just used this in Fritzing and added the pins names as a note.

[image]

````
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>    // Core graphics library
#include <Adafruit_ST7735.h> // Hardware-specific library for ST7735
#include <SPI.h>


#define TFT_CS        10
#define TFT_RST        9 // Or set to -1 and connect to Arduino RESET pin
#define TFT_DC         8


#define TFT_MOSI 11  // Data out
#define TFT_SCLK 13  // Clock out


Adafruit_ST7735 tft = Adafruit_ST7735(TFT_CS, TFT_DC, TFT_MOSI, TFT_SCLK, TFT_RST);

float p = 3.1415926;

void setup(void) {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.print(F("Hello! ST77xx TFT Test"));

  // OR use this initializer (uncomment) if using a 1.44" TFT:
  tft.initR(INITR_144GREENTAB); // Init ST7735R chip, green tab


  Serial.println(F("Initialized"));

  uint16_t time = millis();
  tft.fillScreen(ST77XX_BLACK);
  time = millis() - time;

  Serial.println(time, DEC);
  delay(500);

  // large block of text
  tft.fillScreen(ST77XX_BLACK);
  testdrawtext("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur adipiscing ante sed nibh tincidunt feugiat. Maecenas enim massa, fringilla sed malesuada et, malesuada sit amet turpis. Sed porttitor neque ut ante pretium vitae malesuada nunc bibendum. Nullam aliquet ultrices massa eu hendrerit. Ut sed nisi lorem. In vestibulum purus a tortor imperdiet posuere. ", ST77XX_WHITE);
  delay(1000);

  // tft print function!
  tftPrintTest();
  delay(4000);

  // a single pixel
  tft.drawPixel(tft.width()/2, tft.height()/2, ST77XX_GREEN);
  delay(500);

  // line draw test
  testlines(ST77XX_YELLOW);
  delay(500);

  // optimized lines
  testfastlines(ST77XX_RED, ST77XX_BLUE);
  delay(500);

  testdrawrects(ST77XX_GREEN);
  delay(500);

  testfillrects(ST77XX_YELLOW, ST77XX_MAGENTA);
  delay(500);

  tft.fillScreen(ST77XX_BLACK);
  testfillcircles(10, ST77XX_BLUE);
  testdrawcircles(10, ST77XX_WHITE);
  delay(500);

  testroundrects();
  delay(500);

  testtriangles();
  delay(500);

  mediabuttons();
  delay(500);

  Serial.println("done");
  delay(1000);
}

void loop() {
  tft.invertDisplay(true);
  delay(500);
  tft.invertDisplay(false);
  delay(500);
}

void testlines(uint16_t color) {
  tft.fillScreen(ST77XX_BLACK);
  for (int16_t x=0; x < tft.width(); x+=6) {
    tft.drawLine(0, 0, x, tft.height()-1, color);
    delay(0);
  }
  for (int16_t y=0; y < tft.height(); y+=6) {
    tft.drawLine(0, 0, tft.width()-1, y, color);
    delay(0);
  }

  tft.fillScreen(ST77XX_BLACK);
  for (int16_t x=0; x < tft.width(); x+=6) {
    tft.drawLine(tft.width()-1, 0, x, tft.height()-1, color);
    delay(0);
  }
  for (int16_t y=0; y < tft.height(); y+=6) {
    tft.drawLine(tft.width()-1, 0, 0, y, color);
    delay(0);
  }

  tft.fillScreen(ST77XX_BLACK);
  for (int16_t x=0; x < tft.width(); x+=6) {
    tft.drawLine(0, tft.height()-1, x, 0, color);
    delay(0);
  }
  for (int16_t y=0; y < tft.height(); y+=6) {
    tft.drawLine(0, tft.height()-1, tft.width()-1, y, color);
    delay(0);
  }

  tft.fillScreen(ST77XX_BLACK);
  for (int16_t x=0; x < tft.width(); x+=6) {
    tft.drawLine(tft.width()-1, tft.height()-1, x, 0, color);
    delay(0);
  }
  for (int16_t y=0; y < tft.height(); y+=6) {
    tft.drawLine(tft.width()-1, tft.height()-1, 0, y, color);
    delay(0);
  }
}

void testdrawtext(char *text, uint16_t color) {
  tft.setCursor(0, 0);
  tft.setTextColor(color);
  tft.setTextWrap(true);
  tft.print(text);
}

void testfastlines(uint16_t color1, uint16_t color2) {
  tft.fillScreen(ST77XX_BLACK);
  for (int16_t y=0; y < tft.height(); y+=5) {
    tft.drawFastHLine(0, y, tft.width(), color1);
  }
  for (int16_t x=0; x < tft.width(); x+=5) {
    tft.drawFastVLine(x, 0, tft.height(), color2);
  }
}

void testdrawrects(uint16_t color) {
  tft.fillScreen(ST77XX_BLACK);
  for (int16_t x=0; x < tft.width(); x+=6) {
    tft.drawRect(tft.width()/2 -x/2, tft.height()/2 -x/2 , x, x, color);
  }
}

void testfillrects(uint16_t color1, uint16_t color2) {
  tft.fillScreen(ST77XX_BLACK);
  for (int16_t x=tft.width()-1; x > 6; x-=6) {
    tft.fillRect(tft.width()/2 -x/2, tft.height()/2 -x/2 , x, x, color1);
    tft.drawRect(tft.width()/2 -x/2, tft.height()/2 -x/2 , x, x, color2);
  }
}

void testfillcircles(uint8_t radius, uint16_t color) {
  for (int16_t x=radius; x < tft.width(); x+=radius*2) {
    for (int16_t y=radius; y < tft.height(); y+=radius*2) {
      tft.fillCircle(x, y, radius, color);
    }
  }
}

void testdrawcircles(uint8_t radius, uint16_t color) {
  for (int16_t x=0; x < tft.width()+radius; x+=radius*2) {
    for (int16_t y=0; y < tft.height()+radius; y+=radius*2) {
      tft.drawCircle(x, y, radius, color);
    }
  }
}

void testtriangles() {
  tft.fillScreen(ST77XX_BLACK);
  uint16_t color = 0xF800;
  int t;
  int w = tft.width()/2;
  int x = tft.height()-1;
  int y = 0;
  int z = tft.width();
  for(t = 0 ; t <= 15; t++) {
    tft.drawTriangle(w, y, y, x, z, x, color);
    x-=4;
    y+=4;
    z-=4;
    color+=100;
  }
}

void testroundrects() {
  tft.fillScreen(ST77XX_BLACK);
  uint16_t color = 100;
  int i;
  int t;
  for(t = 0 ; t <= 4; t+=1) {
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int w = tft.width()-2;
    int h = tft.height()-2;
    for(i = 0 ; i <= 16; i+=1) {
      tft.drawRoundRect(x, y, w, h, 5, color);
      x+=2;
      y+=3;
      w-=4;
      h-=6;
      color+=1100;
    }
    color+=100;
  }
}

void tftPrintTest() {
  tft.setTextWrap(false);
  tft.fillScreen(ST77XX_BLACK);
  tft.setCursor(0, 30);
  tft.setTextColor(ST77XX_RED);
  tft.setTextSize(1);
  tft.println("Hello World!");
  tft.setTextColor(ST77XX_YELLOW);
  tft.setTextSize(2);
  tft.println("Hello World!");
  tft.setTextColor(ST77XX_GREEN);
  tft.setTextSize(3);
  tft.println("Hello World!");
  tft.setTextColor(ST77XX_BLUE);
  tft.setTextSize(4);
  tft.print(1234.567);
  delay(1500);
  tft.setCursor(0, 0);
  tft.fillScreen(ST77XX_BLACK);
  tft.setTextColor(ST77XX_WHITE);
  tft.setTextSize(0);
  tft.println("Hello World!");
  tft.setTextSize(1);
  tft.setTextColor(ST77XX_GREEN);
  tft.print(p, 6);
  tft.println(" Want pi?");
  tft.println(" ");
  tft.print(8675309, HEX); // print 8,675,309 out in HEX!
  tft.println(" Print HEX!");
  tft.println(" ");
  tft.setTextColor(ST77XX_WHITE);
  tft.println("Sketch has been");
  tft.println("running for: ");
  tft.setTextColor(ST77XX_MAGENTA);
  tft.print(millis() / 1000);
  tft.setTextColor(ST77XX_WHITE);
  tft.print(" seconds.");
}

void mediabuttons() {
  // play
  tft.fillScreen(ST77XX_BLACK);
  tft.fillRoundRect(25, 10, 78, 60, 8, ST77XX_WHITE);
  tft.fillTriangle(42, 20, 42, 60, 90, 40, ST77XX_RED);
  delay(500);
  // pause
  tft.fillRoundRect(25, 90, 78, 60, 8, ST77XX_WHITE);
  tft.fillRoundRect(39, 98, 20, 45, 5, ST77XX_GREEN);
  tft.fillRoundRect(69, 98, 20, 45, 5, ST77XX_GREEN);
  delay(500);
  // play color
  tft.fillTriangle(42, 20, 42, 60, 90, 40, ST77XX_BLUE);
  delay(50);
  // pause color
  tft.fillRoundRect(39, 98, 20, 45, 5, ST77XX_RED);
  tft.fillRoundRect(69, 98, 20, 45, 5, ST77XX_RED);
  // play color
  tft.fillTriangle(42, 20, 42, 60, 90, 40, ST77XX_GREEN);
}```
````

**LIBRARIES:**

- Go to Sketch -> Include Library -> Manage Libraries
- Search for **Adafruit GFX Library** and install the latest version and install all the dependencies as well when it asks
- Search for **Adafruit ST7735 and ST7789 Library** and install the latest version and install all the dependencies as well when it asks